# Triggering parameterized builds with predefined parameters do not pass the parameter value

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a chain of build jobs: A -> B -> C. I want to pass the source build number as a parameter so all jobs in the chain have an identical build number.

The jobs are triggered by the Parameterized Trigger Plugin (v. 2.32). Each job sets a predefined parameter in the post-build actions in order to inject its own source build number:

```
Parameters: SOURCE_BUILD_NUMBER=${SOURCE_BUILD_NUMBER}
```

Then the triggered job is able to set its build name (section "build environment") using this parameter value:

```
Build Name: mybuildjob#${ENV,var="SOURCE_BUILD_NUMBER"}
```

But this doesn't work. The log output says:

> Unrecognized macro 'SOURCE_BUILD_NUMBER' in 'mybuildjob#${SOURCE_BUILD_NUMBER}'

If I look at the environment variables of a build I cannot find a `SOURCE_BUILD_NUMBER`. What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Is `SOURCE_BUILD_NUMBER` defined in each job as a parameter?

Comment: Yes, as written it's defined in the section post build action in the parameterized trigger plugin as a _predefined parameter_.

Comment: I mean is it defined as a Job Parameter in the Job B and C? Seems to be caused by https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins+affected+by+fix+for+SECURITY-170

Comment: Thanks for the link!! I wasn't aware of this. Would be nice if this would be mention on the plugin page as well! I'll try the suggested workaround and report back.